# How to determine the differentiability of a piece-wise defined function?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, notation

How should one test for differentiability of a function that is piecewise defined?

How is the differentiability  related to one sided derivative in this case? Also, in the limits $\lim_{h\to 0^+}$ or $\lim_{h\to 0^-}$ what do the positive and negative signs beside the zero indicate **graphically**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be differentiable at $x=c$ where near $c$ you have say $f(x)=L(x)$ when $x<c$ and $f(x)=R(x)$ when $x>c$, you need both continuity at $c$ of $f(x)$, and also that the left derivative of $R(x)$ at $c$ matches the right derivative of $L(x)$ at $c$.

For the continuity part, each of the left and right limits must exist and be equal to $f(c).$

Graphically, the two pieces of the graph at $c$ must "hook up", i.e. no jump in the graph (and also the two sides must each hook up to $(c,f(c))$.) And the two slopes from the two sides must match.

Note: the + sign in $\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)$ means that $x$ is approaching $c$ from the right side, and similarly if it was a minus sign it would mean an approach from the left side of $c$.

Comment: in the graphical meaning you are speaking about the alternate definition but i'd like to understand it in terms of h (original definition)...does this mean that the distance h is shrinking from left hand side at h->0- and is shrinking from right hand side at h->0+ ???

Comment: The distance between $f(c)$ and $f(c+h)$ is decreasing as you say, whether $h$ approaches zero from the right or left. But that's not enough for differentiability at $c$. [So far that's only continuity at $c$.] One has to also consider the limiting values of $[f(c+h)-f(c]/h$ as $h$ approaches zero from either side, and these two limits of quotients must be equal for $f$ to be differentiable at $c$.

Comment: thanks, the key sentence you said ::  One has to also consider the limiting values of [f(c+h)−f(c]/h **as h approaches zero from either side**

Comment: but another thing to ask about --> to know the slope of the secant from either side before tending h to zero from either side we should fix a point of the secant at the point we would like to test for differentiability... **does this mean the function MUST be defined at that point before doing the secant line test (before fixing the secant at that point) ? otherwise the graph of f' should contain discontinuity at that point??**

Comment: It's the slope of the tangent line that is relevant, and I assume by the secant line you mean a line through two points on the curve. For the test, you need the point $(c,f(c))$ to be defined, and then take a nearby point $(c+h,f(c+h))$ on either side of $c$. The slope of such a secant line must approach the same thing from either side (as $h \to 0$ from right or left) for the derivative of the piecewise $f$ to exist at $x=c$.

Comment: and if (c,f(c)) is undefined does this mean the curve of f' will be undefined at that point c ??

Comment: Yes on your last comment. For $f'$ to exist at a point $c$ it is necessary that $f(c)$ be defined, as well as the limit of the slopes of secant lines existing.