# Why this trick apparently works to make piecewise function differentiable? (also, difference between right derivative and right limit of derivative?)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

In high school Calculus a few weeks ago we were given the following problem - it has haunted me ever since and I finally decided to ask about it here:

$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
2x^2+x+1\ &\text{if }x\leq 0,\\
ax+b &\text{if }x>0.
\end{array}\right.$$

*1. Determine the values of $a$ and $b$ such that $f$ is continuous for all x-values.*

*2. Determine the values of $a$ and $b$ such that $f$ is differentiable for all x-values. (Hint/reminder: for $f$ to be differentiable, both $f$ and $f'$ must be continuous.)*

---

Part 1 was easy and I believe I understand why it works. And clearly $b=1$ because that's the solution to $a(0)+b = 2(0)^2+0+1$.

Part 2 was conceptually much more difficult. The first issue is that the statement in the question that "for $f$ to be differentiable ... $f'$ must be continuous" is demonstrably false. Being the math nerd that I am, I remembered quickly that in fact the function $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$, where $f(0)=0$, is differentiable at $x=0$ but nevertheless $f'$ is NOT continuous there.

The second tricky thing is that even though my teacher's premise was apparently false, the solution they derived from that premise was apparently correct! (or at least I have no reason to believe it was incorrect) Specifically, they set the derivative at $x=0$ of the top expression, $4(0)+1$, equal to that of the bottom expression, $a$, and quickly found $a=1$ ($b$ is, of course, still 1 as well).

That's a really nifty trick -- just set the derivatives of the two expressions equal to one another and solve. So at this point I'm super confused. **Assuming the method my teacher used did in fact work, *why* did it work?**

Furthermore, when researching this topic I came across the idea of right and left-hand derivatives. My understanding is that those two terms are related to, but distinct from, the left and right-hand limits of the derivative function at a  point. In other words, my understanding is that the left derivative at $x=a$ is defined as....

$$f'_{-}(a)=\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$

... while the limit of the derivative function as $x$ approaches $a$ from the left is simply... $$\lim_{x\to a^-}f'(x)$$

Am I correct that there's a difference between those two concepts (and, regardless, does it matter to my ultimate inquiry?)

I am aware that others have asked somewhat similar questions here in the past (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1774517/derivative-of-piecewise-functions) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950288/how-to-determine-the-differentiability-of-a-piece-wise-defined-function?rq=1)). However, the answers I have seen either gloss over things I'm confused about or otherwise have not helped me achieve full understanding.

I'll note, lastly, that I've also tried to think about this problem graphically. I suppose that has shown me that the teacher's solution was somewhat sensible (it did give me an intuitive idea that the "slopes" need to "match" on each side), but it has not completely convinced me in the way a formal justification would. Furthermore, oftentimes it just takes me back in circles to the difference (if any) between a right-hand derivative and the right-hand limit of the derivative function.

Comment: First off, if a function is not clearly differentiable, you can't use $f'$. It may not be defined. So I have no idea as to what 2. of the question means.

Comment: "Am I correct that there's a difference between those two concepts (and, regardless, does it matter to my ultimate inquiry?)" Yes, you are right. The second limit might not even exist while the first one does (as your example $x^2\sin(1/x)$ shows).

Comment: I think what should have been said for part 2 is that in order for $f$ to be differentiable, it is _sufficient_ that $f$ and $f'$ are both continuous. What was actually written is that it is _necessary_ that $f$ and $f'$ are both continuous, which is a very different claim and (as you found) a false claim.

Comment: Your own example, $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$, illustrates the difference between the left derivative of a function and the left-hand limit of the function's derivative.

Comment: It is not generally necessary that $f'$ be continuous.

Comment: The teacher's trick worked because the left and right functions are both differentiable everywhere, so for the piecewise function to be differentiable the left and right quotient limits must be equal.

Comment: @DavidK Because the left-hand limit of the function's derivative doesn't exist in that case, but the left derivative at 0 is 0? Or for some other reason?

Comment: Because the left-hand limit of the derivative doesn't exist but the left derivative does.

Comment: @DavidK Now, am I correct that for relatively "nice" functions the two concepts converge, i.e. the left limit of the derivative function = the left derivative?

Comment: If by "nice" you mean the derivative is continuous, then I think you get that property by definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For continuity, the only point of concern is $x=0$ and we need
$\lim_{x \uparrow 0} f(x) = 1 =  \lim_{x \downarrow 0} f(x) = b$.

Hence $f$ is continuous everywhere **iff** $b=1$.

Since $f_-(x)= 2x^2+x+1$ and $f_+(x)= ax+b$ are both smooth everywhere, the only way that $f$ can fail to be differentiable at $x=0$ is if $f_-'(0) \neq f_+'(0)$.

Hence we need $f_-'(0) = 1 =  f_+'(0) = a$.

It is not true in general that $f'$ needs to be continuous. In fact, $f'$
may only exist at one point. For example, take $f(x) = x^2 1_\mathbb{Q}(x)$ (indicator function of the rationals multiplied by $x^2$), then $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ but is not even continuous for $x \neq 0$.

In general, if one has $f_-$ and $f_+$ (defined for $x \le 0$ and $x>0$), then to be differentiable at $x=0$ we need $\lim_{x \uparrow 0} f_-(x) = f_-(0) = \lim_{x \downarrow 0} f_+(x)$ (this is just continuity) **and**
$\lim_{h \uparrow 0} {f_-(h) - f_-(0) \over h} = \lim_{h \downarrow 0} {f_+(h) - f_-(0) \over h}$.

In the above case, these two limits are just $f_-'(0), f_+'(0)$.

**Answer to questions in comments**:

In general, suppose we are given $f$ defined as $f_1$ for $x \le 0$ 
and $f_2$ for $x>0$.

Note that the value of $f$ at $x=0$ is $f_1(0)$. (Here, $0$
is not even in the domain of $f_2$.)

Then $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ **iff** the following two limits
exist and are equal:
$$ \lim_{h \uparrow 0} {f_1(h)-f_1(0) \over h} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \lim_{h \downarrow 0} {f_2(h)-f_1(0) \over h} $$
Note that the value at $x=0$ is $f_1(0)$ in both cases.

Now suppose further that there are two functions $g_1,g_2$ that are
differentiable at $x=0$ (that is, two usual sided derivatives at $x=0$),
**and** that $f_1(x)=g_1(x)$ for $x \le 0$ and $f_2(x)=g_2(x)$ for $x>0$.
(Note that since $g_1,g_2$ are differentiable at $x=0$ then they are continuous at $x=0$.)

Then the above limit conditions are equivalent to showing
$g_1(0) = g_2(0)$ and $g_1'(0) = g_2'(0)$.

Note that to conclude this, we only need $g_1,g_2$ to be differentiable at $x=0$. It is not necessary to have anything like $C^1$.

Comment: I'll upvote this, but just want to note that it doesn't completely answer my question because it's phrased at a bit high of a level (and without enough intuitive explanation) for me to reach full understanding.

Comment: (It also doesn't really explain why my teacher's "trick" works for this type of problem.)

Comment: I will give you a full refund.

Comment: It does explain why. Read the last two paragraphs. Carefully.

Comment: The intuition is straightforward, the slope from the right and the slope from the left must match. However, the rest is technical detail, so I'm not sure what you are expecting there. If you have specific questions about the above please ask. However, it is difficult to elaborate unless you are more specific.

Comment: OK, I'll look over it very carefully again and see if I have specific questions. One minor question right now: In your statement that $$\lim_{h \downarrow 0} {f_+(h) - f_-(0) \over h}$$, did you make a typo with the sign in the numerator? Also, does your up-arrow limit notation mean the same thing as the limit from the left, e.g. $\lim_{x\to a^-}$?

Comment: @Will: It means the limit as $h \to 0$ and $h \ge 0$, so the limit **from** the right. It is just the slope 'viewed' from the $x\ge 0$ perspective.

Comment: The above is technical, and depends on $f_-$ being defined on $x \le 0$ and $f_+$ being defined on $x >0$. Just continuity requires that $\lim_{h \uparrow 0} f_-(h) = f_-(0) = \lim_{h \downarrow 0} f_+(h)$.

Comment: So you're sure there's no typo in the above statement? Shouldn't the numerator be ${f_+(h) - f_+(0)}$?

Comment: Well, that was the point of my previous comment. $f_+$ on only defined (in this context) for $x>0$. So $f_+(0)$ is not defined. That is why you need the limit mentioned in that comment to hold. (Essentially, you need to be able to extend the domain of $f_+$ to include $0$)

Comment: But to answer your question, there is no typo.

Comment: In your problem, $f_-(x) = 2x^2+x+1$, $f_+(x)=ax+b$, however, they can be defined everywhere, so you don't need the technicalities. You just need the functions to match at $x=0$ and you need the slope from the left (which is $f_-'(0)$ here) to match the slope from the right  (which is $f_+'(0)$ here).

Comment: I don't want to throw you or anything, but note that if $f_+$ is only defined for $x>0$ then $f_+(0)$ is not defined (and hence $f_+'(0)$ is not defined). However, **if** $\lim_{h \downarrow 0} f_+(h)$ exists (call it $L$), **and** $\lim_{h \downarrow 0} {f_+(h)-L \over h}$ exists, then we can extend the definition of $f_+$ to $x=0$ in such a way that it is continuous and has a right derivative at $x=0$.

Comment: But in your problem above, we can gloss over these details.

Comment: Hmm. Wait does your notation $f_+'(0)$  mean the right derivative of the entire piecewise function at 0, or does it mean the derivative of the positive part of the piecewise function, the function $f_+(x) = ax+b$, at 0?

Comment: In retrospect, bad choice of notation by me. I used $f_-$ for the function defined on $x \le 0$ and $f_+$ for the function defined on $x >0$.

Comment: $f_+'(0)$  as such does not exist since $f_+$ is only defined for $x >0$. However, if we let $f_2(x) =ax+b$, and $f_+(x)=f_2(x)$ for $x >0$, we see that since $f_2'$ is defined everywhere, we can extend $f_+$ to $x=0$ and it must have a right derivative there.

Comment: The problem is that this stuff is very straightforward but gets completely lost in the notational detail.

Comment: Alright, I think I'm done asking questions for now haha. I think I need to spend more time thinking about your answer & the problem. I'm sincerely grateful for your repeated and detailed responses. Some of it has only left me more confused, I'll admit, but your answer helped enough that, unless someone else gives a better answer today (I hope someone else will try!), I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: I don't care about the answer being accepted, but would hate for me to confuse you. Please feel free to continue to ask and I will try to respond as I have time.

Comment: Last question (I hope), that I'm still unclear on (phrased a bit differently): The teacher's method seems to assume (& judging by your answer, this is the key connection between the rigorous method and the teacher's short way) that the right derivative of $f$ at $x=0$ is simply the derivative of $ax+b$. The teacher seems to assume the left derivative of $f$ at $x=0$ is simply the derivative of $2x^2+x+1$, evaluated at $x=0$. Why can the teacher make those assumptions? Does it have anything to do with the fact that both $ax+b$ and $2x^2+x+1$ are of class $C_1$, i.e. continuously differentiable?

Comment: See my edit above. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100075/discussion-between-will-and-copper-hat).